# Accessing full url of all page images Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm experimenting with the Wikipedia API and was trying to get the full urls for all images on a particular page, in this example Google's main page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google).
I found the page id through the use of another API and then attempted to use this information in the following API to get the full urls of all images on that page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=1092923&generator=images&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=xml

I get some of the page images from this but cannot understand why I am not getting all - specifically the logo which is what I was most interested in. Apologies I am aware that there are similar questions which have been asked but I was not able to find one which would assist me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API does not give you all results at once, it defaults to 10 results. You see in the beginning answer that you have a value for the parameter gimcontinue. If you use it like this you get more images: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=1092923&generator=images&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=xml&gimcontinue=1092923|Google_bike.jpg

Alternatively, you can ask for more images at once using gimlimit like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=1092923&generator=images&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=xml&gimlimit=500

Comment: thanks very much perfect! Is there a way of ordering the xml output in terms of the order the images appear on the page from  top to bottom

Comment: Perfect Answer. Saved my day!